# Render a string as HTML in C# Razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am attempting to render an address from my model. The string contains line breaks that I am replacing with a break tag. Although, it is rendering on the page as a string instead as HTML. How can I force my string to render as HTML instead?

**Attempt:**

```
<span id="addressLine">
    @Model.MyData.Address.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
</span>
```

**Result on page:**

```
Address Top<br />Street Name<br />City<br />PostCode
```

**Should be displayed as:**

```
Address Top
Street Name
City
PostCode
```

Comment: you should split the string.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Sorry mate, first day using C#. So I should split it and save it as different variables and render them on different lines?

Comment: Use `@Html.Raw(Model.MyData.Address.Replace("\r\n", "<br />"))`

Comment: @Dom - Cheers, worked perfectly. Post as an answer.

Comment: `<br/>` inside `<span>`? Cringe!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw(Model.MyData.Address.Replace("\r\n", "<br />"))`

Comment: Be careful using this, as if the user's address is `1234 <script>alert('a')</script> lane`, you will have xss problems

Comment: @JohnKoerner - Don't worry, we clean out everything and format the address before saving it in the database. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: This is no longer the best answer. A couple of answers below use a CSS/HTML strategy that avoids the use of `Html.Raw`. The problem with line-breaks is a CSS/HTML one, and modern browsers can be controlled (with CSS/HTML) to behave how you intend.

Answer (score 34):

Use

```
@(new HtmlString(@Model.MyData.Address))
```

It is safer, so that you **avoid potential xss attacks**

See this post:
[Rendering HTML as HTML in Razor](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/displayblog.aspx?permalink=2218)

Comment: How does it avoid potential xss attacks? It is just a wrapper around a string to indicate that when used on a view that the content shouldn't be encoded, so any untrusted content will be displayed the same as Html.Raw.

Answer (score 9):

Use css to preserve the white space

Html

```
<div id="addressLine">
  @Model.MyData.Address;
</div>
```

Css

```
#addressLine {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: This answer is also better because you no longer need to use `Html.Raw`.

Comment: This answer is only about css, not about html encoding or rendering html as is with razor. Which happens serverside, so little to do with css in this case.

Answer (score 8):

To render HTML on blazor you can use [MarkupString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.markupstring?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
=> @((MarkupString)here your string) this will render the string as HTML

```
<span id="addressLine">
    @((MarkupString)@Model.MyData.Address.Replace("\r\n", "<br />"));
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS whitespace property instead of it.
For more details, access http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

It also helps you avoiding Cross-site scripting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)