# How put url to string

Tags: .net, razor, .net-core

In chats 2 users send messages
message have simple model

```
public class Message
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string UserFromId{ get; set; }
        public string ConnectionID{ get; set; }
    }
```

method which send and save message. it work with  SignalR

```
public async Task SendMessage(Messages message)
        {
            
            if (message != null)
            {
                //save to db. Content = string
                var savetoDb = await _chatService.InsertMessageToDb(message);
                if (savetoDb > 0)
                {
                        await Clients.Clients(message.ConnectionIdUserTo).SendAsync("NewMessageFromUser", message);
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
```

the method works and sends and receives messages. but the problem is that if i pass in message url it will be passed as a string like [image: this]

how i can send in string url? maybe you need to clarify something?

Comment: Look if the string is htmlEncoded somewhere. Perhaps on the message rendering

Comment: the string is not encoded where. just displayed on razor like @Model.Content

Comment: go this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284734/render-a-string-as-html-in-c-sharp-razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

big thanks to [B.Lec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6520054/b-lec) my question was solved by @Html.Raw(item.Content)